# Placing paragraph text below h1 on video background

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble  placing the paragraph text centered like the H1 on the video background. I am not sure what I should  use for it. I tried `margin` and `padding` adjustments, but they make the video size bigger which is not what I want.

[image]

```css
/* Background Video */

#background-video>video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

#home {
  position: relative;
}


/* Overlay the Video for Text */

#overlay {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Video Text */

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  height: 40vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id='home'>
    <div id='overlay'>
      <h1>My Name</h1>
      <p id="Info">Web Developer</p>
    </div>
    <section id='background-video'>
      <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source src="Video 3.mp4">
                </video>
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Could you share your full code on codepen.io, I would like to look into this.
I feel `position:absolute;` in a proper way can fix this along with using `transform:translate()` property. 
If you can share the full code, I will try to do it for you :)

Also could you please show the final design that you wish to achieve. I am not really sure how you want your text on Image. I feel, you want it centred

Comment: Hey Imran, sorry I can't post the full code because it's private but the part where it needs fixed is posted so if you know how to I appreciate it.

Comment: I understand, The Image that you have shared, Is that how you expect it to be. Or could you share the Design Image (the one you expect to acheive)

Comment: Sure thing [link](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/12_45.png), so I want the paragraph to go below the h1 which says 'My Name' just like normally would.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can try:)

Using `position:absolute` and `transform:translate();` properties.
And setting a height of `100vh` to `section` element with `id="home"`

**CODEPEN LINK:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/JjNVZWe

```css
*{
 margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#home{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  position:relative;
}
#background-video > video
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 1;
  background:blue;
}

/* Overlay the Video for Text */
#overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

/* Video Text */
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id='home'>
            <div id='overlay'>
                <h1>My Name</h1>
                <p id="Info">Web Developer</p>
            </div>
        
            <section id='background-video'>
                <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source src="Video 3.mp4">
                </video>
            </section>
        </section>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey, tried that it centers below but it increases the video height which is not what I want and is not centered below the H1.

Comment: I do not think this can increase video height as its position is absolute and has nothing to do with height of the video. I believe there is other reason why your video height is increasing :) Anyways, Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the `display: flex` on your overlay element, set the `flex-direction` to `column` and place `align-items: center` to center the items on the vertical axis as the main axis has changed due to direction being column. You can also do a `justify-content` with `space-between` and add any bottom margin to place the p tags content away from the bottom of the parent elements border if you want though it is not needed.

```css
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#background-video > video
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#home
{   
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

/* Overlay the Video for Text */
#overlay
{   
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* Video Text */
h1
{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    height: 40vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id='home'>
            <div id='overlay'>
                <h1>My Name</h1>
                <p id="Info">Web Developer</p>
            </div>
        
            <section id='background-video'>
                <video autoplay loop muted>
                    <source src="Video 3.mp4">
                </video>
            </section>
        </section>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey, tried that [link](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/2_427.png) it increased my video height which is not what I am looking for and still same problem not being displayed below the H1 where I have 'My Name'.

Comment: Try height:`auto`; or try that with `width: fit-content`

Comment: Also you may want to add a reset for padding, margin and box-sizing as well the extra padding/margin/size may be coming from hidden browser margin/padding/.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way of doing it but my problem is I wanted to keep the 40vw,
[link](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/5_113.png) hmm i don't know if there's other way of doing it do without the fit-content or auto.

Comment: The 40VW is on the video?

Comment: Looks like you have 40vw on your height property for the H1... Are you certain you did not want vh instead?

Comment: You can always add a clamp or static height if you want. Maybe a min-height of 40vh? I assume you want that on the video?

Comment: It's on the h1 only, the 40 vw was just to increase the video height because the video has 100% so the content below flows nicely I didn't placed a measurement on the height because of it.

Comment: Yes I would like a min-height on the video that scales with vh.